# How do I query on a subset of ActiveModel records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, arel

I've rewritten this question as my previous explanation was causing confusion.

In the SQL world, you have an *initial record set* that you apply a query to. The output of this query is the *result set*. Generally, the *initial record set* is an entire table of records and the *result set* is the records from the *initial record set* that match the query ruleset.

I have a use case where I need my application to occasionally operate on only a subset of records in a table. If a table has 10,000 records in it, I'd like my application to behave like only the first 1,000 records exist. These should be the same 1,000 records each time. In other words, I want the *initial record set* to be the first 1,000 devices in a table (when ordered by primary key), and the *result set* the resulting records from these first 1,000 devices.

Some solutions have been proposed, and it's revealed that my initial description was not very clear. To be more explicit, I am not trying to implement pagination. I'm also not trying to limit the number of results I receive (which `.limit(1,000)` would indeed achieve).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expound on the use case that you are trying to cover?  I am not understanding whether you are attempting to only be able to work with the first 4 entries or you only want to work on the entries that aren't the first four.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interrupt your question as it makes little sense.  What is your end goal?  To Paginate?

Comment: Simply put, I want to query against a subsection of a table as opposed to the entire table. As an example, I'm looking for a query along the lines of "return the records where some_attribute=100 from the first 100 records in the table (when ordered by `id`)"

Comment: it seems that here `Device.limited.limit(5).offset(5)` you try not to get empty array, but select `5` record, beginning with `5`, because the latest conditions just changes the prevoius or make it more narrow. What is the reason to get the empty array?

Answer (score -1):

This is the line in your question that I don't understand:

> This causes issues though with both of the calls, as limit limits the results of the query, not the database rows that the query is performed on.

This is not a Rails thing, this is a SQL thing.

`Device.limit(n)` runs `SELECT * FROM device LIMIT n`

Limit always returns a subset of the queried result set.

Would `first(n)` accomplish what you want? It will both order the result set ascending by the PK and limit the number of results returned.

Comment: This is getting closer. I want to limit the query set though, not the result set.

Comment: @YWCAHello how would you do that with SQL?

Comment: Excellent question! And one I unfortunately do not have the answer to.

Comment: @YWCAHello sorry, but that was kinda of a loaded question I asked.  The only way that I can see you accomplishing what you want is to remove all records from the DB that you do not want to query against.  Unless you have robust indexing and concrete `where` conditions, you are going to end up doing full table scans and limiting the result set.

Comment: In that case, lets say that we want to pick the first x number of records through a means like `.order(:id).limit(100)`. If we got the value `id_val = Object.order(:id).limit(1).offset(100).first.id` couldn't we then perform the query we wanted to by adding `.where("id < ?", id_val)` to the front of the chain? Can you think of any clever way to do this in a single query? @tagCincy

Comment: I think I understand now.  You can do what you want in Oracle using the ROWNUM key, but not in PG or MySQL (I assuming you are using one of those 2).  `LIMIT` in both MySQL and PG limits the number of records in the return set, not the number of records that a query is run against.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Statements can be chained together.  So if you have your subset, you can then perform additional queries with it.

```ruby
my_subset = Device.where(family: "Phone")
# SQL: SELECT * FROM Device WHERE `family` = "Phone"

my_results = my_subset.where(style: "Touchscreen")
# SQL: SELECT * FROM Device WHERE `family` = "Phone" AND `style` = "Touchscreen"
```

Which can also be written as:

```
my_results = Device.where(family: "Phone").where(style: "Touchscreen")
my_results = Device.where(family: "Phone", style: "Touchscreen")
# SQL: SELECT * FROM Device WHERE `family` = "Phone" AND `style` = "Touchscreen"
```

From your question, if you'd like to select the first 1,000 rows (ordered by primary key, `pkey`) and then query against that, you'll need to do:

```
my_results = Device.find_by_sql("SELECT * 
                           FROM (SELECT * FROM devices ORDER BY pkey ASC LIMIT 1000) 
                           WHERE `more_searching` = 'happens here'")
```

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear. I'm not trying to limit the number of results returned, I'm trying to limit the number of initial records I query against to the first `x` records in the table.

Comment: In sql, you would need to do some sort of query on the ENTIRE data set to get your subset of data, then you can do whatever you want on that. Where this query is just returning the first 1,000 records or checking some column.

Comment: Its not possible to query on a "magical" subset of rows as it would have no idea what subset to query upon, in your (revised) question, you mentioned the first 1000 rows, thus your query would be used get those first 1000 rows as your subset and then do the rest of your query against that.

Comment: I don't remember using the term "magical". Is it possible to combine the first 1000 rows query with the secondary query, or must it be a two step process? I'm trying to avoid returning all of the rows of the first query to the application.

Comment: Updated answer to a new possible solution

Answer (score -2):

You could specifically ask for a set of IDs:

```
Device.where(id: (1..4).to_a)
```

That will construct a `WHERE` clause like:

```
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Don't need to pass a range to the `to_a` function in a `where`

Comment: The only difference would be that a range cause the query to build a BETWEEN clause rather than an IN.

Comment: I'm not directly trying to query against objects 1-4, rather, I'm trying to query the first four objects. In this case, they happen to be the same.